# Why must the solution of an exact linear differential equation satisfy the following requirement?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Theorem**

Let $P,Q: D\to R^2$ be functions of class $C^1(D)$ and $Q(x,y)\neq 0, \forall (x,y) \in D$.

Let $U \in C^1(D)$ such that $\frac{dU}{dx}=P(x,y)$ and $\frac{dU}{dy}=Q(x,y)$.

Then, a one-parameter family of solutions of $P(x,y)dx+Q(x,y)dy=0$ is of the form $U(x,y)=c$ with $c \in R$.

**Example**

Let $2xydx+(x^2-3y^2)dy=0$, the solution is $x^2y-y^3+c=0 |c\in R$.

According to the theorem, the solution is only valid $\forall (x_0,y_0) | Q(x,y)\neq 0$. Why? I can choose the particular solution $x^2y-y^3=0$ and it is true for $(0,0)$, which satisfies that $Q(0,0) = 0$.

**Question**

In the calculation of the solution of an exact differential equation it is irrelevant that $Q(x,y)\neq 0$. Why is it important to the solution?

Comment: The term _solution_ of an ODE usually refers to either a smooth curve or a smooth mapping on an interval. The locus $x^2y-y^3=0$ is a union of three lines at the origin.

Comment: I have drawn the graph and there are three lines that meet at the origin. How does that relate to what $Q(x,y)\neq 0$?

Comment: The condition $Q(x_0, y_0) \neq 0$ is _sufficient_ to guarantee a solution through $(x_0, y_0)$. It could happen there is a solution through $(x_0,y_0)$ even if $Q(x_0,y_0)=0$, i.e., the condition in the theorem is _not necessary_. But at the origin, the level set $x^2y-y^3=0$ is not a smooth solution of an ODE, i.e., is not locally the graph of a $C^1$ function. And as you note, $Q(0,0)=0$.

Comment: I don't understand anything. I know what a level set is, but I don't know how you are relating a level set with the condition. However, this example refutes the theorem: $(y-3x^2)dx-(x-1)dy=0$ whose solution is $y(x-1)+x^3=c ; c\in R$

Comment: According to the source, this solution doesn't need the theorem. Why? I suppose it due to it can be expressed in a explicit form which is defined $\forall x \in R except x=1$ and $Q(1,y)=0$.

Comment: Because of $y$ is the dependent variable, we have $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-P}{Q}$, so any solution $y$ is defined for the differential equation if and only if $Q\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theorem quoted is a special case of the implicit function theorem: If $U$ is a $C^{1}$ function in some plane region $D$ and if $U_{x} = P$ and $U_{y} = Q$ are not both zero, then the ODE
\begin{align*}
  dU &= U_{x}\, dx + U_{y}\, dy \\
  &= P(x, y)\, dx + Q(x, y)\, dy \\
  &= 0
\end{align*}
has solutions $U(x, y) = c$ that are smooth curves. In a bit more detail, if $Q(x_{0}, y_{0}) \neq 0$, there exists a $C^{1}$ function $\phi$ of one variable such that $y_{0} = \phi(x_{0})$, and in some neighborhood of $(x_{0}, y_{0})$ the level curve $U(x, y) = c$ is precisely the graph $y = \phi(x)$.

Regarding the comment/question

> According to the theorem, the solution is only valid [for all] $(x_{0}, y_{0})$ [such that] $Q(x, y) \neq 0$. Why?

1. The first sentence is not quite accurate: The theorem is a *sufficient* condition for existence of a smooth solution in the preceding sense, but not a *necessary* condition. That is, if $Q(x_{0}, y_{0}) = 0$, the theorem does not say anything, because one of its hypotheses is not satisfied; the conclusion may be true or may not be. Particularly, if $Q(x_{0}, y_{0}) = 0$ that *does not guarantee* in general that the level curve $U(x, y) = c$ fails to be the graph $y = \phi(x)$ of a $C^{1}$ function near $(x_{0}, y_{0})$.
2. If your answer book imposes the condition $Q(x, y) \neq 0$, that might be to emphasize that these are the only points where the theorem *guarantees* the level curve $U = c$ is a smooth solution of the ODE $dU = 0$. It might also be that *in this particular example*, being able to write the level curve as $y = \phi(x)$ near $(x_{0}, y_{0})$ is equivalent to the condition $Q(x_{0}, y_{0}) \neq 0$. (That assertion is not a consequence of the theorem alone, however.)

Regarding the comment

> I can choose the particular solution $x^{2}y - y^{3} = 0$ and it is true for $(0, 0)$, which satisfies that $Q(0, 0) = 0$.

3. The equation $x^{2}y - y^{3} = (x - y)(x + y)y = 0$ *does not define a smooth curve* in any neighborhood of the origin. Instead the level set is a union of three lines: $y = 0$, $y = x$, and $y = -x$.
4. The diagram shows the slope field for the ODE
   $$
   2xy\, dx + (x^{2} - 3y^{2})\, dy = 0,
   $$
   i.e., the field corresponding to the vector field $(-Q, P) = (3y^{2} - x^{2}, 2xy)$ whose integral curves are solutions of the ODE.

The blue lines are the level set $x^{2}y - y^{3} = 0$.

The green lines are the set where $Q = 0$. At these points, the slope field is vertical and the theorem does not guarantee we can write solutions locally as $y = \phi(x)$. At each green point $(x_{0}, y_{0}) \neq (0, 0)$, however, $P(x_{0}, y_{0}) \neq 0$ so there exists a $C^{1}$ function $\psi$ such that the level set is the graph $x = \psi(y)$ in some neighborhood of $(x_{0}, y_{0})$.

At the origin matters are worse: $P(0, 0) = Q(0, 0) = 0$, and as noted above the level set of $U$ is not a smooth curve at all.

[image: A slope field for a plane ODE]